# Why is static modulus greater then dynamic modulus in limestone?

Tags: geology, geophysics, geomorphology

Generally dynamic modulus is greater then static modulus and experimental data matches that. But in chalcedonic limestone, the static modulus looks to be greater than the dynamic modulus. What could be the reason for this?

And what exactly is dynamic modulus and static modulus? Is it same as Young's modulus?
[image]